# Dataframe's boxplots are not plotted correctly

Tags: python, pandas, graph, boxplot

I tried plot many boxplots based on different dataframes and got that although i define a new figure for every boxplot, every plot is plotted on the previous boxplots (so just the first is plotted correctly).

The dataframe i created:

```
cpu_util=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cpu_util)
gpu_util=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gpu_util)
cpu_mem=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cpu_mem)
gpu_mem=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(gpu_mem)
disk_c_usage=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(disk_c_usage)
disk_c_fs=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(disk_c_fs)
disk_d_usage=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(disk_d_usage)
disk_d_fs=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(disk_d_fs)
```

and boxplots creation based on aboved dataframes:

```
    boxplot =cpu_util.boxplot(rot=90,fontsize=4,grid=True,showfliers=False,whis=[0,100])
    fig1 = boxplot.get_figure()
    fig1.suptitle('CPU utilization [%]', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
    boxplot.set_ylabel('Utilization [%]')
    boxplot.set_xlabel('Computer name')
    boxplot.set_ylim(0,100)
    fig1.savefig('cpu_util.pdf')


        #### gpu util ####
    boxplot2 = gpu_util.boxplot(rot=90,fontsize=4,grid=True,showfliers=False,whis=[0,100])
    fig2 = boxplot2.get_figure()
    fig2.suptitle('GPU utilization [%]', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
    boxplot2.set_ylabel('Utilization [%]')
    boxplot2.set_xlabel('Computer name')
    boxplot2.set_ylim(0,100)
    fig2.savefig('gpu_util.pdf')


        #### cpu mem ####
    boxplot3 = cpu_mem.boxplot(rot=90,fontsize=4,grid=True,showfliers=False,whis=[0,100])
    fig3 = boxplot3.get_figure()
    fig3.suptitle('CPU memory [%]', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
    boxplot3.set_ylabel('Memory [%]')
    boxplot3.set_xlabel('Computer name')
    boxplot3.set_ylim(0,100)
    fig3.savefig('cpu_memory.pdf')
```

I create 6 boxplots in total (copy here just part of them, but the idea is clear...)

the result i got for the first boxplot (and is plotted correctly):

[first boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pv0C.png)

and the second (as noted, is plotted over the first and can see two green lines for each box instead single line):

[second boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaIPI.png)

Dataframes building is NOT the problem. I checked and they built with correct values.

After a lot of checking, i guess the problem is something with figure defines but fail to put the finger on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to do it:

1. Add `plt.clf()` after each `fig.savefig()` lines. Unless you clear the plot, the program will be overwriting any plot you have there already. `plt.clf()` clears the plot and allow you to start over with the next image.

   I.e.:

   ```
   boxplot =cpu_util.boxplot(rot=90,fontsize=4,grid=True,showfliers=False,whis=[0,100])
   fig1 = boxplot.get_figure()
   fig1.suptitle('CPU utilization [%]', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
   boxplot.set_ylabel('Utilization [%]')
   boxplot.set_xlabel('Computer name')
   boxplot.set_ylim(0,100)
   fig1.savefig('cpu_util.pdf')
   plt.clf()
   ```
2. Check out this example: [matplotlib examples](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/categorical_variables.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-categorical-variables-py)

   There by using `plt.subplots()` you'll  be able to create 3 different plots as subplots and then save them as one image. Of course, you can do a similar thing for 6 plots.
3. You can put `plt.figure()` at the beginning of each new plot, which will create a figure from scratch.

Comment: great :) if it helped you, do you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) the answer? cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create 6 figures you can use a for loop and create each figure in a loop.

```
  for  i in [cpu_util, gpu_util, cpu_mem, gpu_mem]:
      fig, ax= plt.subplots()
      ax.boxplot(i)
      ax.set_title('CPU utilization [%]', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
      ax.set_ylabel('Utilization [%]')
      ax.set_xlabel('Computer name')
      ax.set_ylim(0,100)
      fig.savefig('cpu_util.pdf',dpi=300)
```

Code above creates one figure for each dataframe. If you want to put them into subplots you can use the code below.

```
  c=0 # simple counter
  for  i in [cpu_util, gpu_util, cpu_mem, gpu_mem]:
      row= c//2 # since we have 2 columns row will be either 0 or 1.
      col= c%2 # since we have 2 columns columns also will be either 0 or 1.
      fig, ax= plt.subplots(2,2) # 2 rows and 2 columns.
      ax[row,col].boxplot(i)
      ax[row,col].set_title('CPU utilization [%]', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
      ax[row,col].set_ylabel('Utilization [%]')
      ax[row,col].set_xlabel('Computer name')
      ax[row,col].set_ylim(0,100)
      fig.savefig('cpu_util.pdf',dpi=300)
      c+=1
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.